# can't access variable in another function inside object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code of `javascript`

```
var Obj = {
    init: function () {
        this.over = $('<div />').addClass('over');
        $('body').append(this.over);
        $('.click').on('click', this.show);
    },
    show: function () {
        console.log(this.over);
    }
}

Obj.init();
```

When this does is when user clicks a `.click` link then it triggers `show` function and logs out the dom element created in `init` function. **But the problem is then it logs out undefined. Why?** How to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this :

```
var Obj = {
init: function () {
    this.over = $('<div />').addClass('over');
    $('body').append(this.over);
    $('.click').on('click', this.show);
},

show: function () {
    // here the 'this' is the button , not the obj object ..
    console.log($('.over'));
}
}

Obj.init();
```

another option :

```
var Obj = {
init: function () {
    this.over = $('<div />').addClass('over');
    $('body').append(this.over);
    var that = this;
    $('.click').on('click', function(e){
       that.show.call(that, e); // calling the show function with call, causing 'this' to be obj
    });
},

 // 'this' is the obj
show: function (e) {
    console.log(this.over);
}
}

Obj.init();
```

Comment: hope it helps , and solves your problem , if you need help understand something , let me know.

Comment: Thank you for you help. One more thing can you look at this http://jsfiddle.net/SQGsZ/1/ . Why me is not logged out?

Comment: Obj.me; => Obj.me(); // in line 9 !

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the scope of that `this` (`Obj`).

Use the following code to solve your problem.

```
var Obj = {
init: function () {
    this.over = $('<div />').addClass('over');
    $('body').append(this.over);
    $('.click').on('click', $.proxy(this.show, this));
},

show: function () {
    console.log(this.over);
}
};

Obj.init();
```

learn more about [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Answer (score 1):

Because jQuery injects the DOM element that was clicked on into 'this' as opposed to the 'Obj' object. One solution is closure:

```
var Obj = {
  init: function () {
    this.over = $('<div />').addClass('over');
    $('body').append(this.over);
    $('.click').on('click', this.show());
  },

  show: function () {
    var self = this;
    return function () {
        console.log("over:", self.over);
    }
  }
}
Obj.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You *pass* the function stored in `this.show` to `on`. When it gets called, it is not called in the context of `Obj` so `this` is not `Obj`.

You need to create a new function which isn't dependent on being called in the context of `Obj`.

The easiest way to do this is with `bind`:

```
$('.click').on('click', this.show.bind(this));
```

But this has [limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=bind).

You can also use a closure:

```
var myObj = this;
var show = function () {
    myObj.show()
}
$('.click').on('click', show);
```

Answer (score 0):

When binding a function to an event with jquery, the context in which this function is called is the dom object that has been clicked.

```
var Obj = {
init: function () {
    this.over = $('<div />').addClass('over');
    $('body').append(this.over);
    var that = this;
    $('.click').on('click', function(){ 
        // console.log( this ) will log the dom object
        that.show.call( that ) 
     } );
},

show: function () {
    console.log(this.over);
}
}

Obj.init();
```